# virtual networking on single machine

Tags: networking, simulation, virtual-machine, lan

Is it possible to run more than one virtual machines on my PC using virtual box/ vmware/ virtual pc etc and connecting all of them together? So if i write an application like a chat program or something else, it treats running image as separate machine.
All machines should have different IP addresses and they could have different OS as well.

Please tell me how can i do this.

Comment: Yes, if you have enough system resources (mostly RAM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to start with a machine that has loads of RAM and CPU power. Other than that there is nothing difficult. All you have to do is install virtual box(Freely available) And download several Linux flavors(You can use windows too) mount the drives in virtual box and start creating the machines. You can start all of them together if you want to and they will have different IP addresses.

Read 
http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=33943#33943

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html

Finally
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal

Comment: There can be some tricky parts to networking them all.  If you want them networked internally only, that is usually the default.  If you want a BOOTP or other local server to assign them all accessible addresses, you need to configure bridged networking instead of NAT.  If you are behind a linksys or dlink type home firewall box, it will assign each VM an address if the VM is visible (i.e., in bridged mode) but they will only be accessible from within your home -- unless you also configure the home firewall... and only with port forwarding will you typically be able to connect them all....

Comment: Even though i hadnt tried it. But accepting it, since I'll take time to work on that. thanks @Grrrrr